# Unity3d not showing compiler errors

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

First off all I'm new to unity so this might be a stupid question.

At the bottom of the unity window compiler errors are usually shown, I've been making a game based on some code from a YouTube video, I seem to have a problem where when I press play no compiler errors are shown but on the play window I get the "You must fix all compiler errors before you can play" message, I've tried to fix the scrips manually but i cant see the problem, there's 5 scripts but without knowing which its hard to find, monoDevelop also doesn't see a problem.

So my main question is how to fix errors not appearing on the bottom?
Thanks for any help.

P.S. I've changed most of the code from the video as it was lacking, it ignored "Don't Repeat Yourself" etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Console window contains compiler errors. You should clear the console and then try a generation (ie hit play and let it say "fix compiler errors") so that you don't get cluttered with duplicates.

Note that because Unity uses a compiler all its own, it's not unheard of to see compiler errors that MonoDevelop doesn't. The opposite is also true, but will not stop your game since it's Unity's compiler you want to worry about. These mismatches are rare, however, so always be sure to try a build (F7 by default) in MonoDevelop.

Also make sure your scripts are sacved and have refreshed the most up-to-date changes in the Unity Editor as this can lead to all sorts of errors that are a nightmare to track down. The best way to do this is to highlight your script and see if the code looks correct in the inspector.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I was using a type like a variable but I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

You will also get this error when opening a project from a shared drive. When opening the project, it will immediately complain that you are having compilation errors and you should open in safe mode...which ever you choose, it will NOT show you any compile errors, but will not run either.
[Before loading project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve9lx.png)

On ignore you get the same as when you go to safe mode and exit it (duh).

[Console after load Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxBzm.png)

[Pressing play and showing Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUkkS.png)

Seems for some reason this is not allowed.